How to find the needed item inside a nested item in an array?
I have a struct like this in code, which is Identifiable and has nested items as well:
struct Item: Identifiable {
    
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var nameOfItem: String
    var nestedItems: [Item]
    
    init(nameOfItem: String, nestedItems: [Item]) {
        self.nameOfItem = nameOfItem
        self.nestedItems = nestedItems
    }

}

var myArray: [Item] = [Item]()

My issue is after building my array, if I need to update an item I know the id of that Item but I do not know how to look for that id and find it in correct way. look this photo, I can look each item of myArray to find the item that match to my looking id, and if myArray items dose not have the item I am looking for, I have to start looking inside of nested items of each array item, which would take tons of time. Looking to find out if there is a faster way to find the needed item.


How big are your array and sub-arrays? If there are not many items, a simple depth first search algorithm might be good enough for your needs. If you have enough memory but need a faster lookup speed, you can try using a dictionary. The key would be the ID and value would be the Item object.

It is big like 50000 or 100000 items, I can change the array to dictionary like var myDic: [string : Item] = [string : Item]() which string would be UUID.string also in Item as well, but at the end i have to loop or filter each dic layer by layer, which would be the same issue again.

But searching the keys of each dictionary would be fast

With 50 to 100 thousand objects maybe you are better of storing them in a database and let the database engine do the searching

To ... update an item I know the id of that Item but I do not know how to look for that id and find it in correct way, use recursion, such as:
 func findItem(withID id: UUID, in items: [Item]) -> Item? {
     for item in items {
         if item.id == id {
             return item
         }
         if let foundItem = findItem(withID: id, in: item.nestedItems) {
             return foundItem
         }
     }
     return nil
 }

 

EDIT-1:
You can use the same approach (recursion) to construct a Dictionary [UUID: Item] once.
Then after that, you can directly access/update the desired item id, no overhead to access.
var itemDictionary = createItemDictionary(items: myArray)
 
 itemDictionary[item2.id]?.nameOfItem = "Mickey Mouse"  // <--- here
 
 func createItemDictionary(items: [Item]) -> [UUID: Item] {
     var itemDictionary: [UUID: Item] = [:]
     for item in items {
         itemDictionary[item.id] = item
         itemDictionary.merge(createItemDictionary(items: item.nestedItems)) { (_, new) in new }
     }
     return itemDictionary
 }
 
 


Thanks a lot, It is same as I mentioned in my question, you are also looking inside each item one by one.

You can use the same approach (recursion) to construct a Dictionary [UUID: Item] once.
Then after that, you can directly access the desired item id, no overhead.
 Updated my answer to use a dictionary.

